# What's wrong in this?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    cout<<"The Addition is:"<<endl;
    cin>>a+b;
}
```

It's showing that `cin`,`cout` and `endl` are Undeclared...

Comment: what's with `cin >> a + b` ?

Comment: add using namespace std; and don't forget to return something (main returns int)

Comment: @ekeren: Confusingly, for the `main` function (and only the `main` function), the return statement is optional, even though the `int` return type is not. If execution reaches the end of the `main` function without a return statement being encountered, the effect is as if `0` was returned.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the use of the `std` namespace. Use `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::endl`.

I am not sure what your intention is with this line though.

```
cin>>a+b;
```

You'll get a compile error. After you put the `std` in there, the line is equivalent to:

```
std::cin>>(a+b);
```

which is not a valid operation.

Answer (score 3):

You want `std::cout` and `std::endl` etc.  Most of the C++ standard library is in `namespace std`.  You could also say `using namespace std;` at the top if you want an alternative...but please note that should never be done in a header file, only .cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

The input stream and output stream `cin`, `cout` and some other streams like `endl` are declared in a `namespace` called `std`.
Either you have to use the namespace in your code with all the streams or you have to declare the namespace with `using` keyword.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    std::cout<<"The Addition is:"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>a+b;
}
```

or

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    cout<<"The Addition is:"<<endl;
    cin>>a+b;
}
```

WHAT IS `cin>>a+b;` ANYWAY? looks like you wanted to print the result of `(a+b)` operation with it. So the code should be, `cout<<(a+b)`. `cin` is used to take inputs.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    cout<<"The Addition is:"<<endl;
    cout<<a+b;
}
```

Hope it helped..

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    cout<<"The Addition is:"<<endl; //wrong
    cin>>a+b;                       //wrong
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code.